# What is the difference between "git push -f" and "git push -ff"?

Tags: git, git-push

I know what git push -f ( --force) does , but I saw that -ff is used also.
Initially I thought that is was the abbreviation of --force-with-lease but I didn't found any reference regarding "-ff" in the man.

Cheers,

Comment: Not many places actually , just a couple of references, an article around git tips and an older question here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Could it be `git pull --ff` which means `git fetch` + [`git merge --ff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff)?

Answer (score 2):

Because you used a single-dash qualifier, its context is interpreted as a set of single-letter qualifiers. Therefore `-ff` is the same as `-f -f`. You can use `-fffffff`... git just interprets it as repeated `-f`.